# PHP & JS to print using Dot Matrix Printer

Tags: javascript, php, json, inject, dot-matrix

I have develop my project in PHP and Javascript, In this project I have to print a bill using Dot Matrix printer via Browser, But it gives error like Print preview failed...... How can I rectify that problem, I have use JS(window.print) for printing the paper

Comment: your JS code has no knowledge of what the printer is, you can't fix it with your own code. It's probably an issue between the browser, the O/S and the printer itself. Does this happen in all browsers, or just one? Have you got the printer drivers properly installed?

Comment: Thank you for your concern, but still the error is happen

Comment: did you check the things I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I had try these things